# перебрать значения input`s

Tags: javascript

Имеется код, в котором несколько `input`, в которых атрибут `type` имеет значение `text` и несколько `input` со значением `type = checkbox`, нужно собрать данные в массив

```
<input type="text" class="delete" name="date_statement_del" value="">
<input type="text" class="delete" name="initiator_del" value="">

<input class="delete checkbox" name="secretariat_del" type="checkbox">
<input class="delete checkbox" name="deportament_del" type="checkbox">
<input class="delete checkbox" name="kadr_del" type="checkbox">
<input class="delete checkbox" name="urist_del" type="checkbox">

<input type="text" class="delete" name="date_of_del" value="">
<input type="text" class="delete" name="comment_del" value="">
```

пробовал собрать вот таким образом

```
$('input.delete').each(function(i,el){
        var val = $(el).val();
        var name = $(el).attr('name');
        deleteData[name] = val;
    });
    anketData['deleteData'] = deleteData;
```

но не знаю, как собрать значения и из текстовых и из чекбоксов так, чтоб был массив с элементами типа `name = val` ещё слабо знаю javascript, поэтому прошу помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы получить значение из `checkbox` можете использовать `.is(':checked')`. В остальном у вас рабочий код.

Так же ознакомьтесь с [этим комментарием](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23768878/7678419), в нем хорошее описание работы с `checkbox` в зависимости от версии jQuery

```js
var deleteData = {};

$('input.delete').each(function(i, el) {
  if ($(el).attr('type') === 'checkbox') {
    var val = $(el).is(':checked');
  } else {
    var val = $(el).val();
  }
  var name = $(el).attr('name');
  deleteData[name] = val;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="delete" name="date_statement_del" value="">
<input type="text" class="delete" name="initiator_del" value="">

<input class="delete checkbox" name="secretariat_del" type="checkbox">
<input class="delete checkbox" name="deportament_del" type="checkbox">
<input class="delete checkbox" name="kadr_del" type="checkbox">
<input class="delete checkbox" name="urist_del" type="checkbox">

<input type="text" class="delete" name="date_of_del" value="">
<input type="text" class="delete" name="comment_del" value="">
```

Comment: большое спасибо)